# Get assets from an asset source

Tags: assets

I have a bunch of images that aren't related to any entries but are in an asset source. Let's call this 'My Images'.

How do I just grab those assets? I can't find anything in the docs that suggests this is possible—it seems such an obvious use-case though I'm sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is [craft.assets](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.assets)

> You can access your site’s assets from your templates via craft.assets. It returns an ElementCriteriaModel object.

Use `sourceId` for the parameter.

To find the sourceId, look at the `craft_assetsources` table in the database. There doesn't seem to be any way to query for [AssetSourceModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetsourcemodel).

Comment: Yes I saw this. It's pretty cryptic though, how do I find the sourceId?

Comment: Thanks, this works. Not a very intuitive solution though, I would hope there is a better way than having to look up id's in the database!

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch assets related to a certain source by using the [craft.assets.source](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.assets#source) method and passing in the source handle.

Assuming your handle is 'my_images', the following will do the job:

```
craft.assets.source('my_images')
```

You avoid having to lookup db IDs that way.

Comment: Note: If you want to pull _all_ Assets, be sure to set the `limit` parameter to `null`, i.e. `{% set assets = craft.assets.source('my_images').limit(null) %}`, otherwise your query will be limited to 100 Assets.